# Determine through javascript if another URL exists

Tags: javascript

I am working with a servlet which serves up an image. However, it  takes about 30 seconds for this to be generated. When complete, it appears on an OpenLayers interactive map.

I am trying to figure out a way for the user, who is at www.test.com to get confirmation the image is being processed or is complete, which is located at www.test2.com. If I open test2.com, I can see that the page is trying to load. When complete, the image also appears on my map on test.com.

However, I can't figure out how to test if this image exists or not. I am looking for something probably like

```
    if(image exists at http://test2.com) {alert("request is done");
```

or possibly

```
    if(http://test2.com is loading) {doing something);
```

I just don't want the user sitting by if the request fails. If it fails, the url will complete its load - however, no image will appear. Any guidance will be very appreciated! Thanks!

Kyle

Comment: If the page blocks while the image is being loaded you could add an `img` element and then check for when it fires it's `load` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a different server, JavaScript will not be able to make any type of Ajax request to that server to see if it exists. You would have to have a proxy on the local domain which could make a head request to the second domain.

If you are waiting until the image is loaded to work with it, you can always do an image preloader, but that will take the full time for the image to render before the onload event fires.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = theUrl;
img.onload = function() {
    nextStep(this);
};
img.onerror = function() {
     imgLoadingError(this);
};
```

Comment: This doesn't have to be ajax and therefore wouldn't be subject to the same origin policy (as evidenced by the fact that the image does presently work in some map element).  You can include `img`s from mostly wherever you want.

Comment: Works perfectly! I can at least show that the process is in the works with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IF you have control over the other server, you could put a small image on that server and do something like this: (Untested code, typed in directly)

```
var img = new Image();
// Note the order of these two statements
img.onload = function()("The image loaded! Server must be up");
img.src = "http://example2.com/myflag.png";
```